# Split String based on delimiter and convert to n level Pair of Pair based on count of delimiter

Tags: java

There is a hashmap and below is the requirement :

```
    Map<String, Object> objectmetainfo = new HashMap();
    objectmetainfo.put("userdetails.info.metadata.user.home.address.details", "address");
    objectmetainfo.put("userdetails.info.metadata.user.id", "id");
    objectmetainfo.put("userdetails.info.metadata.userSupervisor.id", "id");
    objectmetainfo.put("info.metadata.code", "code");
    objectmetainfo.put("zip", "zip");
```

1. Get all the records of hashmap and iterate it
2. Split the Key based on delimiter and convert it to Pair or Hashmap
3. The number of delimiter will vary in each string

Below should be the output :

```
    E.g.: For "userdetails.info.metadata.user.home.address.details", "address", below output is required
         HashMap<userdetails, HashMap<info, HashMap<metadata, HashMap<user, HashMap<home, HashMap<address, Map<details, address>>>>>>>

    or Pair<String, Object> pair = new Pair("userdetails", new Pair("info", new Pair("metadata", new Pair("user", new Pair("home", new Pair("address", new Pair("details", "addressvalue")))))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your string won't be crazy long this would work, otherwise you'd get a StackOverflow error.l

I did this using a recursive approach

1. Split keys by "."
2. Convert them to the list iterator
3. Iterate this list recursively to create a nested map
4. At the end of recursion put the value from `objectmetainfo` map.
5. Create an empty result map and recursively merge all the results.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
    public Map<String, Object> nestedMaps(Iterator<String> keys, String value) {
        if (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            Map<String, Object> nestMap = nestedMaps(keys, value);
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(key, nestMap);
            if (Objects.equals(nestMap, null))
                map.put(key, value);
            return map;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void mergeNested(Object srcObj, Object targetObj) {
        if (srcObj instanceof Map && targetObj instanceof Map) {
            Map<String, Object> srcMap = (Map<String, Object>) srcObj;
            Map<String, Object> targetMap = (Map<String, Object>) targetObj;
            for (String targetKey : targetMap.keySet()) {
                if (srcMap.containsKey(targetKey)) {
                    mergeNested(srcMap.get(targetKey), targetMap.get(targetKey));
                } else {
                    srcMap.putAll(targetMap);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public Map<String, Object> objectmetainfo = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    objectmetainfo.put("userdetails.info.metadata.user.home.address.details", "addressValue");
    objectmetainfo.put("userdetails.info.metadata.user.id", "id");
    objectmetainfo.put("userdetails.info.metadata.userSupervisor.id", "id");
    objectmetainfo.put("info.metadata.code", "code");
    objectmetainfo.put("zip", "zip");

    public Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : objectmetainfo.entrySet()) {
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(e.getKey().split("\\.")));
        Map<String, Object> nestedMaps = nestedMaps(keys.iterator(), String.valueOf(e.getValue()));
        mergeNested(result, nestedMaps);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

I printed out all the hashmaps using toString method.
**Output:**

```
{
    zip= zip,
    userdetails= {
        info= {
            metadata= {
                userSupervisor= {
                    id= id
                },
                user= {
                    id= id,
                    home= {
                        address= {
                            details= addressValue
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    info= {
        metadata= {
            code= code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There would be max 10 delimeters, {userdetails={info={metadata={user={home={address={details=addressValue}}}}}}}
{userdetails={info={metadata={user={id=id}}}}} in above 2 records the key is same till userdetails, info, metadata, user   so rest values should be clubbed     like **{userdetails={info={metadata={user={home={address={details=addressValue}}, id=id}}}}}**

Comment: Can we avoid second recursive call ?

Comment: I have posted the optimized method to avoid the 2nd recursive call

Answer (score 0):

Below is the modified logic to remove 2nd recursive call, with this method we are passing the objMap as reference and finally we will have the objMap ready with result

```
Map<String, Object> objMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : getObjectMetaInfoMap().entrySet()) {
            populateMetaDataMap(keys.iterator(), String.valueOf(e.getValue()), objMap, true, StringUtils.EMPTY);            
        }

public static Map<String, Object> populateMetaDataMap(Iterator<String> keys, String value, Map<String, Object> objMap, boolean newCall, String matchingKey) {
        if (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            if(objMap.get(key) != null && objMap.get(key) instanceof Map) {
                return populateMetaDataMap(keys, value, (Map<String, Object>) objMap.get(key), newCall, matchingKey );
            } else  {
                if(newCall) {
                    newCall = false;
                    matchingKey = key;
                }
                Map<String, Object> nestMap = populateMetaDataMap(keys, value, objMap, newCall, matchingKey);
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                if (Objects.equals(nestMap, null))
                    map.put(key, value);
                else
                    map.put(key, nestMap);

                if(key.equals(matchingKey)) {
                    if(Objects.equals(nestMap, null)) {
                        objMap.put(key, value);
                    } else {
                        objMap.put(key, nestMap);
                    }
                }
                return map;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```